# How to split the text after dot (.) in pandas and create new column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, regex, loops, split

From df1 =

| Filename |
| --- |
| `apple.pdf` |
| `sample.xlsm` |
| `new.docx` |
| `Arigo.tiff` |
| `sec.docx` |
| `sample2.xlsm` |

Need to generate df2 =

| Filename | Filetype |
| --- | --- |
| `apple.pdf` | PDF |
| `sample.xlsm` | excel |
| `new.docx` | document |
| `Arigo.tiff` | tiff |
| `sec.docx` | document |
| `sample2.xlsm` | excel |

Answer (score 3):

Use a mapping dictionary and [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
# add all mappings here
d = {'pdf': 'PDF', 'xlsm': 'excel', 'docx': 'document', 'tiff': 'tiff'}

df['Filetype'] = df['Filename'].str.extract('\.([^.])$', expand=False).map(d)
```

*If you want to keep the extension in case the mapping is absent from the dictionary, use `replace` instead of `map`.*

Comment: Thank you so much
I tried the exact same step you suggested. The filetype column gets filled up with Nan Values.

Comment: @Vivek then your values don't match? Check the output of `df['Filename'].str.extract('\.([^.])$', expand=False).unique()` you should have keys from `d`